# SendKeys on selenium webdriver once in a while sends text in upper case in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-10, sendkeys

SendKeys on selenium webdriver once in a while sends text in upper case in Internet Explorer 10  - for example a login page:

```
        var wait = WebDriverWaitObject();
        wait.Until(d => this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("uid")));
        this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("uid")).Clear();
        this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("uid")).SendKeys(username);
```

This happens sporadically on IE only and no other browser. Is there a bug with send keys?

Comment: Are you using the 64 bit version of the IE driver?  If so, give the 32 bit version a try.

Comment: what's the value of username? Is it hardcoded or randomly generated.

Comment: Hi Richard, I am using the 32 bit version. The 64 bit version just runs exteremely slowly - dont really know why but have been sticking to the 32 bit as a result.

Comment: kkdjfl - I am using a hard coded in username - it is a parameter used from the App.config in c#.

Comment: I have the reverse problem -- sometimes sendKeys uses lower case, even though I specified all upper-case letters.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't be surprised if it was a bug. I'd suggest changing your IE version from 64 bit -> 32 bit or vice versa to test.

Also if you're on 10.0.11 (November 12, 2013) try an older build. For example when I use an older build of chrome sometimes it resolves these kind of issues until the selenium community sends a fix for that browser version.

Lastly, if you're using random generated usernames. Try using a downcase / lower method on the username before sending it to keys. Something like

```
random_username = "John"
lowercase_username = random_username.lower()
```

then inject `lowercase_username` into your selenium code

```
this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("uid")).SendKeys(lowercase_username)
```

Comment: Hi Russel, the username is static but i could just give this a go and run the automation tests several times.